# How to implement a 'back' and 'forward' in bash using alt-left and alt-right?

Tags: bash, shell, directory, scripting, stack

Question is basically it. Trying to implement 'back' and 'forward' functionality using the given key combinations. I'm thinking the best way is to create a stack of visited directories, one for forward, one for back. Is this the best way? Is there a variable that already holds this information that I can call? I had this before I realized that I can't just hold the most recent directory.

```
previous_wd='~'
next_wd='~'
cd()
{
    previous_wd=$(pwd)
    builtin cd "$@"
}

back_to_previous_directory()
{
    next_wd=$(pwd)
    cd "$previous_wd"
}

forward_to_previous_directory()
{
    cd "$next_wd"
}

up_a_directory()
{
    cd ..
}

# \C-u clears the line
bind '"\e[1;3D":" \C-uback_to_previous_directory\n"'        # go back a directory on alt+left
bind '"\e[1;3A":" \C-uup_a_directory\n"'                    # go up a directory on alt+up
bind '"\e[1;3C":" \C-uforward_to_previous_directory\n"'     # go forward a directory on alt+right
```

Comment: Does `cd -` maybe do what you are trying to implement?

Comment: It is not clear what you mean by "previous"/"forward"/etc. Give a concrete example of how cwd should change using your bindings. What should happen if you type `cd another_dir` or `popd` without using a binding?

Comment: @khansh : Going back is trivial (using `popd`, if you use `pushd` instead of `cd` to change directories), but going forward is not provided by bash. In this case, you indeed have to write your own functions. Your approach is not bad, but you need to store a  **list** of the directories visited so far instead of `previous_wd` and `next_wd`, so that you can go forward/backward in the list. I suggest you use a bash array for this, and you also need a pointer (index into this array to point to the place of the directory where you are right now.

Answer (score 1):

You might be interested in using [`pushd`](https://ss64.com/bash/pushd.html) and [`popd`](https://ss64.com/bash/popd.html) instead of `cd`.

These two commands should be used together - `pushd` (push directory) will push the current directory onto the stack, and navigate to a new one (provided as a parameter). `popd` (pop directory) will return to the previous directory, and remove it from the stack

```
addison:~$ pushd /tmp
addison:/tmp$ pushd /etc
addison:/etc$ popd
addison:/tmp$ popd
addison:~$ popd
```

These should let you effectively navigate back and forth. Just use `pushd` every time you would ordinarily `cd`, and use `popd` to go back to the last location!